# Using ifstream to read in the data from a file and store it in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream

I have a text file which looks like that:

```
Mercury     0.39    0
Venus       0.72    0
Earth       1.0 1
Mars        1.52    2
Jupiter     5.2 67
Saturn      9.53    63
Uranus      19.2    27
Neptun      30.1    14
```

There is a program which reads in the data from this file so that it is stored in array and it looks like that:

```
/********************************************************************************
 *
 * Planets.cpp: program reads data from the file planets.dat and prints the 
 *              information. Objects of classPlanet are used to store and print
 *              the data
 *
 * Copyright (C) October 2014               Stefan Harfst (University Oldenburg)
 * This program is made freely available with the understanding that every copy
 * of this file must include this header and that it comes without any WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY.
 ********************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "classPlanet.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Planet planets[8];
  ifstream pdata;

  pdata.open("planets.dat");

  for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    string name;
    double d;
    int    n;
    pdata >> name >> d >> n;
    planets[i] = Planet(name, d, n);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) 
    planets[i].print();

}
```

I would be grateful if you help me understand the line " data >> name >> d >> n; ". Why do the values of name, d and n change in each iteration? **Where do we specify which line or column of the text file the program should read in?**

Comment: If you dont know how it works, I'm assuming you didn't write it?

Comment: No , i did not. Its a solution to the exercise and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about the >> (extraction) operator?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: Thanks! It was important :-)!

Answer (score 0):

`data >> name >> d >> n` first skips whitespace, then it reads a string, then it skips whitespace, then it reads a double, then it skips whitespace, then it reads an int.
It is exactly the same as

```
data >> name;
data >> d;
data >> n;
```

You don't specify a line or column - the stream has a "current position" it keeps track of and it reads from that point.
In fact, there is no way to specify which column or line to read from a stream - you need to write your own code that breaks the input down into lines and columns.

If you want to get the contents of specific columns, the simplest way is to just not use the contents of the ones you're not interested in

```
int main()
{
    ifstream data("planets.dat");
    // Print all the planets' names
    while (data)
    {
        std::string name;
        double d;
        int n;
        data >> name >> d >> n;
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Then, in the next loop iteration, the stream continues reading another string, double, and int, and so on."_

I have noticed that. But why is this so, if i only use "i" while specifying the loop (it is not inside the loop)?

_"From there, it reads a string, a double, and an int (all separated by whitespace)."_

I have also noticed that. But how would it look like if I wanted to read in only first two columns. Or just one column?

I still dont understand how this line " data >> name >> d >> n; " works.

Comment: @joa Added some details. It's difficult to go into more detail without writing a book, so I recommend that you consult yours.